# Python two dimensional list built using abstract classes is yielding the same value in different locations

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, abstract-class, pass-by-reference

## The problem

This is my first real attempt at Python.  I am building a simple chess game so I can learn the language but I haven't gotten very far.  Please excuse me if the answer to this is obvious to everyone but me.  I spent all of today trying to figure this out, scouring the web to no avail (except to find out that this 2d list setup I am using somewhat of a contentious subject amongst Python users).

The problem is that all 16 of my `pawn`s are somehow all printing out `2` (as in Player 2) when there should be 8 printing as `1` and 8 printing as `2`.  I believe the problem is they are the same object with 16 different references, but I can't quite figure out how to fix it, and I have tried many different things (including `deepcopy`) but I keep getting the same result.

I have three files so far: `piece.py`, `pawn.py`, and `board.py` (which consists of a two-dimensional list of a class called `square`):

## piece.py

```
from abc import ABC, ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class piece(ABC):

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def symbol(self) -> str:
        raise NotImplementedError

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def legalmoves(self) -> list:
        raise NotImplementedError

    @classmethod
    def __init__(self, side: int):
        if (side == 1) or (side == 2):
            self.side = side
        else:
            raise ValueError('Side must be 1 or 2')
    
    @classmethod
    def checkmove(self, move: list) -> bool:
        legal = False
        for legalmove in self.legalmoves:
            if (move[0] == legalmove[0]) and (move[1] == legalmove[1]):
                legal = True
        return legal

    @classmethod
    def getsymbol(self) -> str:
        return str(self.side) + self.symbol
```

## pawn.py

```
from piece import piece

class pawn(piece):

    symbol = 'pn'
    legalmoves = [[0,1],[0,2]]
```

## board.py

```
from piece import piece
from pawn import pawn

class square(object):
    
    def __init__(self, row: int, column: int):
        self.row = row
        self.column = column
        self.occupied = False
        self.piece = None

    def setrow(self, row: int):
        self.row = row

    def setcol(self, col: int):
        self.column = col

    def setpiece(self, piece: piece):
        if self.occupied:
            raise ValueError("Square is occupied")
        else:
            self.piece = piece
            self.occupied = True

    def getrow(self) -> int:
        return self.row

    def getcol(self) -> int:
        return self.column

    def getpiece(self) -> piece:
        return self.piece

# Set up board
num_rows = 8
num_cols = 8
board = []
for r in range(num_rows):
    row = []
    for c in range(num_cols):
        row.append(square(r,c))
    board.append(row)
    row = None

# Fill with pieces
for c in range(num_cols):
    board[1][c].setpiece(pawn(1))
    board[6][c].setpiece(pawn(2))

# Draw board
print('    -----------------------------------------------------------------')
print('    |       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|')
print(' 8  |       |//---//|  ---  |//---//|  ---  |//---//|  ---  |//---//|')
print('    |       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|')
print('    -----------------------------------------------------------------')
print('    |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |')
print(' 7  |//' + board[6][0].getpiece().getsymbol() + '//|  ' + board[6][1].getpiece().getsymbol() +
     '  |//' + board[6][2].getpiece().getsymbol() + '//|  ' + board[6][3].getpiece().getsymbol() +
     '  |//' + board[6][4].getpiece().getsymbol() + '//|  ' + board[6][5].getpiece().getsymbol() +
     '  |//' + board[6][6].getpiece().getsymbol() + '//|  ' + board[6][7].getpiece().getsymbol() + '  |')
print('    |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |')
print('    -----------------------------------------------------------------')
print('    |       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|')
print(' 6  |       |//---//|  ---  |//---//|  ---  |//---//|  ---  |//---//|')
print('    |       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|')
print('    -----------------------------------------------------------------')
print('    |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |')
print(' 5  |//---//|  ---  |//---//|  ---  |//---//|  ---  |//---//|  ---  |')
print('    |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |')
print('    -----------------------------------------------------------------')
print('    |       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|')
print(' 4  |       |//---//|  ---  |//---//|  ---  |//---//|  ---  |//---//|')
print('    |       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|')
print('    -----------------------------------------------------------------')
print('    |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |')
print(' 3  |//---//|  ---  |//---//|  ---  |//---//|  ---  |//---//|  ---  |')
print('    |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |')
print('    -----------------------------------------------------------------')
print('    |       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|')
print(' 2  |  ' + board[1][0].getpiece().getsymbol() + '  |//' + board[1][1].getpiece().getsymbol() +
      '//|  ' + board[1][2].getpiece().getsymbol() + '  |//' + board[1][3].getpiece().getsymbol() +
      '//|  ' + board[1][4].getpiece().getsymbol() + '  |//' + board[1][5].getpiece().getsymbol() +
      '//|  ' + board[1][6].getpiece().getsymbol() + '  |//' + board[1][7].getpiece().getsymbol() + '//|')
print('    |       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|')
print('    -----------------------------------------------------------------')
print('    |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |')
print(' 1  |//---//|  ---  |//---//|  ---  |//---//|  ---  |//---//|  ---  |')
print('    |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |')
print('    -----------------------------------------------------------------')
```

## output:

```
    -----------------------------------------------------------------
    |       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|
 8  |       |//---//|  ---  |//---//|  ---  |//---//|  ---  |//---//|
    |       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|
    -----------------------------------------------------------------
    |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |
 7  |//2pn//|  2pn  |//2pn//|  2pn  |//2pn//|  2pn  |//2pn//|  2pn  |
    |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |
    -----------------------------------------------------------------
    |       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|
 6  |       |//---//|  ---  |//---//|  ---  |//---//|  ---  |//---//|
    |       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|
    -----------------------------------------------------------------
    |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |
 5  |//---//|  ---  |//---//|  ---  |//---//|  ---  |//---//|  ---  |
    |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |
    -----------------------------------------------------------------
    |       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|
 4  |       |//---//|  ---  |//---//|  ---  |//---//|  ---  |//---//|
    |       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|
    -----------------------------------------------------------------
    |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |
 3  |//---//|  ---  |//---//|  ---  |//---//|  ---  |//---//|  ---  |
    |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |
    -----------------------------------------------------------------
    |       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|
 2  |  2pn  |//2pn//|  2pn  |//2pn//|  2pn  |//2pn//|  2pn  |//2pn//|
    |       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|
    -----------------------------------------------------------------
    |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |
 1  |//---//|  ---  |//---//|  ---  |//---//|  ---  |//---//|  ---  |
    |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |///////|       |
    -----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What's up with all those `@classmethod`s? Are you under the impression that you're supposed to mark normal methods with that? You're not.

Comment: I was under the impression that you marked `@classmethod` for methods you wanted to be inherited as-is

Comment: Nope. It does something [entirely unlike that](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod).

Comment: You don't need to do anything special to have a method be inherited. That's the default, and there's no built-in way to turn it off.

Comment: Oh, well I thought it meant that they couldn't be altered, but I just removed all the `@classmethod` statements and now it works, so thanks